# The ini4J Library change the comment signifier from ';' 'to '#'

Tags: java, comments, ini4j

i use the ini4J library to manipulate an ini File. 
The Method store() change the comment signifier in every line from ';' to '#'.
Now my application which is using this ini file can't read this typ of comment.
Are there any options to prevant this change?
If not, do you now other ini parser then the ini4j?

Best regards
Alex

Comment: I'd consider ini4j broken in that case.

Comment: I think this is a setting but i can't find anything to change this behavior

Comment: I just tried to figure that out, too. But I couldn't find anything on their website. Comments are not even mentioned in examples etc ... That's why I consider it broken in that respect. Maybe you could issue a change request or bugreport or something. OR maybe you could try to fix it in the code and issue a pull request ...

Comment: Thank you, but i can't wait for a change. Do you know any other library which do something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But meanwhile, you could compile your own fixed version: in `AbstractFormatter` they have this line which I think is the cause: `private static final char COMMENT = '#';`

Comment: I tryed this already. I Import the source code, but there are to many Errors which i can't fix. So I can't to compile the code. For Example: The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods Map<String,Profile.Section>.remove(Object, Object), BasicProfile.remove(Object, Object)

Comment: I think the Errors are caused by using the JRE 1.8. But I can't fix it until now.